# Can apps downloaded under another Apple ID be transferred to new iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, apple-id, data-synchronization

I'm recently planning to upgrade my iPhone from an 8 plus to a 14 plus. There is an app, Shadowrocket, I purchased an vpn service, along with an bought version of Shadowrocket from others, so I have to download the app under another Apple ID. The country I'm in, the app store does not have the app.

That is not downloaded under my personal Apple ID, I'm concerned about whether, as the title says, the app can be transferred to an new iPhone.

ps. the 8 plus is on iOS 15.7.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've removed the spoiler tags but it's still not clear quite what your sequence of events is.

Apps themselves do not transfer from phone to phone - they are re-downloaded from the App Store, even if you set up the new phone from a backup of the old.
You cannot transfer any app to a different owner. If it was downloaded under different credentials it will need those credentials again to re-download - which would not be possible if it's not on your country's app store.

Comment: That would solve my problem, thank you. In the case of sequence of events are easy, the app is downloaded under another apple id firstly, then for the upgrade of phone(yet to happen). Because of the quick set up new iPhone from another iPhone thing, I'm thinking if ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING on the old phone will be on the new phone when doing such setup. I suppose that's a no for my question. Thanks again.